# TestNG test inheritance and groups

Tags: java, inheritance, testng, grouping

We have DAO tests that should run against both the real DAO/database, and against a mock dao to verify that the mock dao behaves the same as the real dao. To this end, we have a structure like this:

```java
public abstract class DAOTestBase
{
    public void testSimple()
    {
        // dummy assertion
        assertTrue(true, "Hello");
    }
}


@Test(groups = "fast")
public class TestMockDAO extends DAOTestBase
{
    // setUp/tearDown and helper methods for mock
}


@Test(groups = "slow")
public class TestDAO extends DAOTestBase
{
    // setUp/tearDown and helper methods for real DB
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work - TestNG doesn't think that the `testSimple` method is a test and hence won't run it. So instead I tried to annotate the `testSimple` method (or the `DAOTestBase` class):

- A `@Test` annotation without any groups will lead to the same effect - the test won't run for either `fast` nor `slow` groups.
- A `@Test` annotation with groups `fast` and `slow` will lead to the opposite effect - both `TestMockDAO` and `TestDAO` will be run regardless of whether only fast or only slow tests should be run.
- A `@Test` annotation with a different group, say `common`, plus added `dependsOnGroups="common"` annotations in both `TestMockDAO` and `TestDAO` will also not work unless `common` is included in the groups to run which leads again to case 2 above (both `TestMockDAO` and `TestDAO` are run).

In the end, what I'm looking for is a way to be able to define the group for the inherited tests in the sub class, but it seems as if the `@Test` annotation is only applied to test methods in that very same class, not also to inherited methods that don't have a `@Test` annotation. Is there any other way to achieve this (without overriding all methods in the sub classes) ?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working through a similar situation.

A way to make test cases run is to use something like:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { SomeTests.class });
  testng.run();
}
```

Reference: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Unforunately I am currently unable to get it to report the test cases within **SomeTests**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply adding a `@Test` annotation on top of DAOTestBase? Each subclass will override it with its own group and this should make the method in the base a test method.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. The inherited methods will be in the default group (or whatever group I specify in the `@Test` annotation of the base class) and not in the groups that the respective sub class is in.

Answer (score 1):

I am using TestNG 6.14.3 version and I found a solution using `priority` annotation.

Example:

1. I have a base test class:

   ```
   public class TestBase {    
      @Test(priority = 0)
      public void testA()  {        
          assertTrue(true, "testA");
      }
   }
   ```
2. And another extended test class:

   ```
   public class Test2 extends TestBase {
      @Test(priority = 1)
      public void testB() {        
          assertTrue(true, "testB");
      }
   ```

   }
3. When I run `Test2` test class, I obtain the following esult:

   ```
   testA: true
   testB: true
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

The methods in the base class are in "base" group, but need to check if the test have been initialized.

```
public abstract DaoTestBase {
    private boolean initialized = false;

    @Test(groups = "base")
    public void testSimple() {
        if (!initialized) { return; }

        // dummy assertion
        assertTrue(true, "Hello");
    }
}
```

The test is initialized in the child, in the BeforeClass annotated method.

```
@BeforeClass
protected void initialize() {
    super.initialized = true;
}
```

If you annotate the parent class instead of the methods, you must pass inheritGroups=false and the group, since it inherits also the group of the base class and it will not work.

Now, you must run TestNG to check groups base,fast or base,slow. Both tests will be executed, but the one not initialized will do nothing.

It is ugly, and I would not recommend it (it looks better to redefine the methods in child and call the according super method), but in my case I need priority in my test methods, and I want to avoid that repetition in each child class.